# Data not rendering on html but shows up on console log - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I can pull the JSON data from my server side and display it in the console log, Just unable to render on the HTML page.  Wrong syntax maybe?

I'm trying to access data from my MongoDB and displaying it via Angular. I've added some additional options from around the web to display the data in a table and filter/sort/etc...  I'm sure it has something to do with my `*ngFor`.  I've tried ' `let ticket of tickets.obj` and a few others, no luck.

My ts file.

```
this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/filter', JSON.stringify(filterOptions), httpOptions)

.subscribe( res => {
  this.tickets = res;
  this.tickets = Array.of(this.tickets);
  this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRowCount / this.rowCount);
  console.log('Fetched Tickets');
  console.log(this.tickets);
},
  err => {
    console.log('Error fetching tickets');
  }
);
```

**HTML**

```
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngIf="tickets.length == 0">
          <td colspan="4" align="center" valign="middle">
            No Records Found.
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr *ngFor="let ticket of tickets; let i = index;">
          <td>{{i+1+offset}}</td>
          <td>{{ticket.resolution}}</td>
          <td>{{ticket.ticketId}}</td>
          <td>{{ticket.status}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
```

The table is blank. It should have data that shows on the console log.

[image]

Comment: so your this.http.post is returning data?

Comment: change your loop to this `*ngFor=let ticket of tickets[0].obj`

Comment: this.tickets = res[0].obj; -> Cannot read property 'obj' of undefined  |  this.tickets = res.obj -> property obj does not exist on type Object | and the solution that worked for me was changing the ngFor= let ticket of tickets[0].obj.  I would've never thought of that.  Thank you all for helping.

Comment: Hameed, yes, it does return data.  I know right, the example I used from the web used post instead of get.  I think it has something to do with the filtering on server side (newbie here just my best guess).

Answer (score 0):

Array what you want to bind is `obj` property in a element of result array.

this will works:

```
...
  subscribe( res => {
  this.tickets = res[0].obj;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

there are have some problem there:
 - the response is array and first element is what you need
You should use this.tickets = res[0].obj.
Hope my answer can help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON response array stored in `obj` array variable, so make it work your code just replace below code it will work

```
this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/filter', JSON.stringify(filterOptions), httpOptions)

.subscribe( res => {
  this.tickets = res.obj; //obj is array elements
   this.tickets = Array.of(this.tickets);
  this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRowCount / this.rowCount);
  console.log('Fetched Tickets');
  console.log(this.tickets);
},

  err => {
    console.log('Error fetching tickets');
  }
);
```

Hope this will help!